# The spectrum of an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space is closed in $\mathbb R$.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In an attempt to solve the following exercise in the book *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians* by Brian Hall:

> Suppose that $A$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and that (real) numbers $\lambda_m$ in the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ converge to some $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. Using Proposition 9.18, show that $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$.

where Proposition 9.18 states that $\lambda\in\sigma(A)\Leftrightarrow \exists ~\psi_n\in \text{Dom}(A)$, $\|\psi_n\|=1$, such that $\|(A-\lambda I)\psi_n\|\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, I show that $(A-\lambda_n I)\psi~\rightarrow (A-\lambda I)\psi$ uniformly on Dom($A$):

> Suppose $\lambda_m\rightarrow \lambda$. Then for all $\psi\in$Dom($A$)
> \begin{align}
> \|(A-\lambda_m I)\psi-(A-\lambda I)\psi\|&= |\lambda_m-\lambda|\|\psi\|=|\lambda_m-\lambda|,
> \end{align}
> and thus $\forall \epsilon>0~~\exists~N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $\|(A-\lambda_n I)\psi-(A-\lambda I)\psi\|<\epsilon$.
> To my knowledge, since $N$ does not depend on $\psi$ we have uniform convergence.

so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|(A-\lambda I)\psi_n\| = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\|(A-\lambda_m I)\psi_n\|= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|(A-\lambda_m I)\psi_n\|=0.$ Which completes the exercise. The last equality follows from  $\lambda_m\in\sigma(A)$  and Proposition 9.18.

I guess I am asking for you input on this approach (if it is correct), and suggestions to alternative approaches.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you define $\psi_n$ ? For every $m$ you have a sequence $\{\psi_{n,m}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ i.e. a sequence depending on $m.$

Comment: I suggest that for every $m$ you choose an appropriate $\psi_{n_m,m}$ and compose the sequence $\psi_n$ basing on the chosen elements.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc $\psi_n$ is a sequence of unit vectors in the domain of $A$ such that  $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$ implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|(A-\lambda I)\psi_n\|=0$. This sequence is proven to exist in the above mentioned book. Perhaps I should put braces to indicate that it’s a sequence?

Answer (score 3):

The resolvent set $\rho(A)$ of a self-adjoint $A: \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$ is open, and the spectrum is the complement of this set. To see that the resolvent set is open, suppose $A-\lambda I$ has a bounded inverse $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Then, for $\delta$ such that $|\delta|\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\| < 1$, the following is invertible
$$
      A-\lambda I-\delta I = (A-\lambda I)(I-\delta(A-\lambda I)^{-1})
$$
with inverse
$$
       (A-\lambda I-\delta I)^{-1}= \\
= (I-\delta(A-\lambda I)^{-1})^{-1}(A-\lambda I)^{-1} \\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\delta(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\right)^n(A-\lambda I)^{-1}.
$$
So the resolvent set of $A$ is open, which makes the spectrum closed.

Comment: @disintegration I can’t follow how the conclusion that ‘the resolvent set is open’ is obtained from the above arguments, perhaps due to my limited knowledge on the subject.

Comment: @ThatoTsabone : I expanded the final equation a bit more for clarity. This should help. Keep mind that $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$ holds for a bounded operator $x$, provided that $\|x\| < 1$.

Comment: @disintegration: Ah! I see.... What would be the difference if I first write $A-\delta I = (A-\lambda I)[I-(\delta-\lambda)^{-1}]$ for some $\lambda$ in the resolvent set and $\delta\in\mathbb{C}$, and only then take $\|(A-\delta I)^{-1}\| \cdot |\lambda - \delta | < 1$. I ask because the conclusion is not clear (to me) if we take $\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\| |\delta|<1$

Comment: @ThatoTsabone : I don't see how $A-\delta I=(A-\lambda I)[I-(\delta-\lambda)^{-1}]$ is an equality. Can you explain? This would say that $A-\delta I$ and $A-\lambda I$ are scalar multiples of each other, which they are not.

Comment: @disintegration: I meant $A-\delta I= ( A-\lambda I)[I -(\delta -\lambda)(A-\lambda I)^{-1}]$

Comment: @ThatoTsabone : With the correct identity as you have written in this last comment, you can see that, if $|\delta-\lambda|\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\| < 1$, and if $(A-\lambda I)$ is invertible, then $A-\delta I$ is invertible. And that means that $A-\delta I$ is invertible for all $\delta$ in a neighborhood of $\lambda$. So, the resolvent set is open. And that makes the spectrum closed because the spectrum is the set complement of the resolvent set.